# How to put name and registration number in a form

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-access

I'm creating a database which stores client related information, in which there are two tables:
  **A.** Client registration
  **B.** Work done.
So I have created 2 forms:
  **a.** to register the client in A.
  **b.** to collect and fill the work done information into B.

A. & B. has relationship with fields like registration number and name. So as work flows b. is sub form.  b. contains 2 parts: b1. is the main form and b2. contains all work done related textboxes. Now when a client comes for subsequent appointments only the name should be searched (this search form is created) opening b. with  provided name and registration number from A. in b1. and b2. should be empty to be filled.

How to achieve this? As per our Q & A site's's rule, I have Googled read a maximum number of articles and watched videos until I got confused to the limit.

[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)  **Work Done form**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**New Patient Registration form**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Patient Registration table**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Work Done**</sup>

Comment: "As for the forum's rule" - this is **not** a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: Thanx DavidPostill

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByNhat5zv-EAMkxjaTlGQ21abDg

Comment: As asked by karel screen shot's link is posted in  comment

Comment: Once again THANK YOU for editing and adding screen shots to my question

Comment: Created a select query with parameters of name and registration number but no improvement.